# Rematch/Effects- Error running test cases written with react testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write unit test cases for my models using react testing library but i am facing some issues executing the test cases.

My effects.js

```
export async function getStoredData(param1, store, param2) {
try {
    dispatch(setLoading(true, 'getStoredData'));
    // Check if key exists in store
    const inputKeyCode = getInputKeyCode([param1, param2]);
    let response = getUserDataState(store)[inputKeyCode];
    if (!response) {
      response = await getUserApi(param1, param2);
      this.setUserData({ keyCode: inputKeyCode, keyValue: response });
    }
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch error
  } finally {
    dispatch(setLoading(false, 'getStoredData'));
  }
}
```

My reducers.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userData: {},
};

const setUserData = (state, { key, value }) => ({ // {key: value}
  ...state,
  userData: {
    ...state.userData,
    [key]: value,
  },
});
```

effects.test.js

```
import { getUserApi } from '../../../api/common';

jest.mock('../../../store', () => ({ dispatch: jest.fn() }));
jest.mock('../../../api/common', () => ({ getUserApi: jest.fn() }));

describe('getStoredData', () => {
  const responseData = {};
  setWith(responseData, 'data.userInformation', 12345);
  const setUserData = jest.fn();

  test('success', async () => {
    getUserApi.mockResolvedValue(responseData);
    await testModel.effects().getStoredData.call({ setuserData });
    expect(setuserData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(setuserData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(12345);
  });

  test('failure', async () => {
    getUserApi.mockRejectedValue(errorMsg);
    await testModel.effects().getStoredData.call({ setuserData });
    expect(showNotification).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(showNotification).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error');
  });
});
```

This gives me below error-

```
Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
At line- expect(setuserData).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Can someone help me understand what i am doing wrong? I guess i am doing some mistake in calling the setuserData. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to test a react component? What is `testModal`? What scope is `dispatch` in in `getStoredData` in effect.js? The call to `getStoredData` doesn't quite seem to match its signature. TBH I don't even see any react-testing-library test code here either. This question needs a lot of help.

Comment: I am trying to test my model. I am trying to write a unit test case for it for coverage. Yes, Probably i am doing the mistake while making a call to getStoredData in my effects.test.js.